# How do I replace the Heroku gem with Heroku Toolbelt?

Tags: heroku

I know that there are closely related question to mine but they did not help me.

I'm learning the whole rails, gem, git, heroku concept and liking it a lot.
When I issued heroku command line actions (Ubuntu linux) I received warnings that the gem was deprecated and I should install the toolbelt.
I ran the full wget install of the tool belt:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

But now when I use the heroku command line I still get the deprecated warning.
I suspect I have to get rid of the heroku gem but I'm not sure how to do that ? I want to be sure to do it correctly so it's not later loaded again via bundler.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The uninstall command will remove any gem.  In this case, you want to use the following:

```
gem uninstall heroku
```

Comment: The above blog post was helpful. But it seems that the key is to  uninstall as you suggest. I ran the gem uninstall. It asked to also delete the heroku executable. I chose no. Then I ran `heroku version` again. But now I get a `Gem::LoadError`. It's coming from `rubygems/dependency.rb` and the message is `Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.8,...`.  There are many, many more items listed, including `heroku-api`. I suspect I need to change a dependency somewhere from `heroku` to `heroku-api`. But I can't find where that would be.

Comment: I can't get anything to work. I can't track down that dependency problem. I'm reverting to the Heroku gem so I can keep working through the Hartl tutorial.It's not critical to update to the heroku-api gem at this point.

Comment: Is that error coming when you run your app?  If so, do you have the heroku gem in your Gemfile?  If so, take that out.

Comment: The heroku toolbelt is already installed. I did remove the heroku gem from my gemfile `gem uninstall heroku`.  But now when I run `heroku version` or any other heroku from the command line I get the above mentioned dependency errors.

Comment: Will, I am having this same problem to.  Despite uninstalling the heroku gem, installing toolbelt and updating paths with `nano /etc/paths`, it keeps looking in the gems for heroku.  I'll let you know if i figure anything out

Comment: WIll, the following worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674686/heroku-toolbelt-install-problems

Comment: If you inadvertently answered 'no' when asked to delete the executable, then the easiest thing to do is re-install the gem and immediately uninstall it, responding 'Y' the second time.

Answer (score 4):

I had issues getting Toolbelt to work.  I am running OSX so my solution may not work for your Ubuntu linux setup.  I still thought I might share just in case. Here are the steps I used to get it to work:

1. Remove the heroku gem by running `gem uninstall heroku`.  It did ask if I wanted to `remove executables: heroku`.  Be sure to choose yes.
2. Go to [https://toolbelt.heroku.com/][1] and download / install the Toolbelt app.
3. On the Toolbelt page it mentioned that `/usr/local/heroku/bin` will be added to your `PATH`.  I was not seeing this and was not sure if it is becuase I am running zsh instead of bash.  I went ahead and opened my .zshrc file and added it to my `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that. Take a look at my comment to the next answer below. I ended up with Gem:LoadError.

Comment: Regarding the first step: it's possible that you have multiple versions of the gem; be sure to choose to remove all of them (you'll get a list before actual removing, one option available will be to remove all of them).

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to relaunch your shell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (be sure to choose yes when it ask if you want to remove executable: heroku)

```
gem uninstall heroku --all
```

Source (last comment): http://johntwang.com/blog/2011/09/13/remove-heroku-toolkit/