# Heroku Toolbelt install problems

Tags: heroku, rvm, heroku-toolbelt

I uninstalled the heroku gem and installed the Heroku Toolbelt and am running into issues getting it working w/ RVM.

`heroku version` command works everywhere except my current project folder.

In my project folder I get

`'/Users/cmalpeli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:223:in 'block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable heroku (Gem::Exception)
    from ./bundler_stubs/heroku:16:in``

Running `which heroku` in my project directory returns:

`./bundler_stubs/heroku`

everywhere else it returns

`/usr/bin/heroku`

I'm sure it has something to do w/ RVM - but I don't quite understand how that works, so would appreciate a bit of help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure `heroku` is not part of your `Gemfile` - it should not be there.

then remove `./bundler_stubs/heroku`:

```
rm -f ./bundler_stubs/heroku
```

it is possible that `./bundler_stubs/heroku` is part of your project and was committed by one of your coworkers, the stubs should not be part of the project.